# \BeforeEndgroup similar to \AfterGroup?

Tags: hooks, etextools

Is there a command similar to `etextools`' `\AfterGroup` which allows to execute a number of commands right *before*, not after the current group ends?

Comment: One might image redefining `\endgroup` to allow this but it would be risky and not cover other end-of-group cases (`}`, table cells, ...).

Comment: Possibly with LuaTeX; the actions of TeX when a group ends are not exposed at the user's level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the answer to this question is no. Plain TeX has a primitive  `\aftergroup` that saves one token for processing after the current group. The `etextools` macro `\AfterGroup` just takes a sequence of tokens and applies `\aftergroup` to each one. Since there is no TeX primitive that does something like `\beforeendgroup` and it would be impossible to implement `\aftergroup` in TeX, I think you're out of luck on this one.

Comment: As far as I know, `\AfterGroup` globally defines a new macro to expand to the argument and passes this new macro to `\aftergroup`, but that's just a detail.

Comment: Oh yeah, that would be more efficient.

Answer (score 4):

`LuaMetaTex` has introduced three new primitives related to this question. The primitives are:

- `\aftergrouped`: similar to `aftergroup`, but can process several tokens (like `etextools`'s `\AfterGroup`).
- `\atendofgroup`: like `\aftergroup`, but it restore the token before the group end.
- `\atendofgrouped`: like `\aftergrouped`, but it restore the tokens before the group end.

They are described in section 3.7.2 and 3.7.3 of `LuaMetaTeX`'s manual.

Here is an example demonstrating them (process the code with context lmtx):

```
%% Tests 1 - 4 are from LuaMetaTeX's documentation

\starttext

{ 
  \aftergroup A \aftergroup B \aftergroup C
test 1 : }

{
  \aftergrouped{What comes next 1}
  \aftergrouped{What comes next 2}
  \aftergrouped{What comes next 3}
test 2 : }

{
  \aftergroup A \aftergrouped{What comes next 1}
  \aftergroup B \aftergrouped{What comes next 2}
  \aftergroup C \aftergrouped{What comes next 3}
test 3 : }

{
  \aftergrouped{What comes next 1} \aftergroup A
  \aftergrouped{What comes next 2} \aftergroup B
  \aftergrouped{What comes next 3} \aftergroup C
test 4 : }

{
  \atendofgroup A \aftergroup B 
  \atendofgrouped{What comes next 1} 
  \aftergrouped{What comes next 2} 
test 5 : }

{
  \aftergroup A \atendofgroup B 
  \aftergrouped{What comes next 1}
  \atendofgrouped{What comes next 2}  
test 6 : }

\def\testA{\def\A{A}}
\def\testB{\def\B{B}}
{
  \atendofgroup\testA \aftergroup\testB
  \atendofgrouped{\def\C{C}} \aftergrouped{\def\D{D}} 
test 7 : } 
\meaning\A\ \meaning\B\ \meaning\C\ \meaning\D


\stoptext
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just a blind shot.

```
\def\beforeendgroup#1{\begingroup\def\tmpbeforeendgroup{#1\endgroup}\aftergroup\tmpbeforeendgroup}
```

Downside is that from `\beforeendgroup` to `\endgroup` everything is inside another group. And it doesn't work with `}` or `\egroup` as of this moment :)

Comment: Possibly better, using `\AfterGroup` `\newcommand*\BeforeEndgroup[1]{\begingroup\AfterGroup{#1\endgroup}}`.

Comment: One disadvantage of that is that it only works if you know the current group is a `\begingroup` `\endgroup` pair, because the `\begingroup` that your `\BeforeEndgroup`  inserts is ended by the end of the group in the code. If the group is delimited with braces or `\bgroup` and `\egroup`, it will cause an error.

Comment: @HoodChatham I know, I wrote it in the answer to leave that clear. It's not at all a complete solution. In any case, what OP wants to achieve can probably be solved with a few hooks in the correct place.

Comment: My bad, I apparently can't read.