# ConTeXt failed with remember picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, context

I want to compile this example :

```
\setuppapersize[A4]
\usemodule[tikz]
\usetikzlibrary[calc,positioning]
\usemodule[fullpage][style={cm,empty}]
\setupfullpage [margin=0cm]
\usecolors[crayola]
\definecolor[bleu][x=3bbaba]
\starttext
\starttikzpicture[remember picture,overlay]
 \draw[bleu,step=2mm](current page.south west) grid (current page.north east);  
 \stoptikzpicture

\stoptext
```

main.log file :

```
resolvers       > globbing > confusing filename, name: 'README.TXT', lower: 'readme.txt', already: 'README.txt'

resolvers       > globbing > confusing filename, name: 'README.TXT', lower: 'readme.txt', already: 'README.txt'

resolvers       > globbing > confusing filename, name: 'README.TXT', lower: 'readme.txt', already: 'README.txt'

resolvers       > globbing > confusing filename, name: 'README.TXT', lower: 'readme.txt', already: 'README.txt'

system          > 
system          > ConTeXt  ver: 2023.09.04 19:15 LMTX  fmt: 2023.9.5  int: english/english
system          > 
system          > 'cont-new.mkxl' loaded
open source     > level 1, order 1, name '/home/aviroum/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkxl/cont-new.mkxl'
system          > beware: some patches loaded from cont-new.mkiv
close source    > level 1, order 1, name '/home/aviroum/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkxl/cont-new.mkxl'
system          > files > jobname './main', input './main.tex', result './main'
fonts           > latin modern fonts are not preloaded
languages       > language 'en' is active
system          > synctex functionality is enabled, expect 5-10 pct runtime overhead!
open source     > level 1, order 2, name './main.tex'
open source     > level 2, order 3, name '/home/aviroum/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkiv/colo-imp-crayola.mkiv'
close source    > level 2, order 3, name '/home/aviroum/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkiv/colo-imp-crayola.mkiv'
colors          > system 'crayola' is loaded
open source     > level 2, order 4, name '/home/aviroum/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/fonts/mkiv/type-imp-texgyre.mkiv'
close source    > level 2, order 4, name '/home/aviroum/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/fonts/mkiv/type-imp-texgyre.mkiv'
fonts           > defining > font 'texgyretermes-regular', feature 'locl', script 'latn', no language 'dflt'
modules         > 'tikz' is loaded
open source     > level 2, order 5, name '/home/aviroum/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/modules/mkxl/m-tikz.mkxl'
open source     > level 3, order 6, name 'pgfutil-common.tex'
open source     > level 4, order 7, name 'pgfutil-common-lists.tex'
close source    > level 4, order 7, name 'pgfutil-common-lists.tex'
close source    > level 3, order 7, name 'pgfutil-common.tex'
open source     > level 3, order 8, name 'pgfutil-context.def'
close source    > level 3, order 8, name 'pgfutil-context.def'
open source     > level 3, order 9, name 'pgfrcs.code.tex'
close source    > level 3, order 9, name 'pgfrcs.code.tex'
open source     > level 3, order 10, name 'pgfsys.code.tex'
open source     > level 4, order 11, name 'pgfkeys.code.tex'
open source     > level 5, order 12, name 'pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex'
close source    > level 5, order 12, name 'pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex'
close source    > level 4, order 12, name 'pgfkeys.code.tex'
open source     > level 4, order 13, name 'pgf.cfg'
close source    > level 4, order 13, name 'pgf.cfg'
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def

open source     > level 4, order 14, name 'pgfsys-pdftex.def'
open source     > level 5, order 15, name 'pgfsys-common-pdf.def'
close source    > level 5, order 15, name 'pgfsys-common-pdf.def'
close source    > level 4, order 15, name 'pgfsys-pdftex.def'
open source     > level 4, order 16, name 'main.pgf'
close source    > level 4, order 16, name 'main.pgf'
close source    > level 3, order 16, name 'pgfsys.code.tex'
open source     > level 3, order 17, name 'pgfkeys.code.tex'
close source    > level 3, order 17, name 'pgfkeys.code.tex'
open source     > level 3, order 18, name 'pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex'
close source    > level 3, order 18, name 'pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex'
open source     > level 3, order 19, name 'pgfsysprotocol.code.tex'
close source    > level 3, order 19, name 'pgfsysprotocol.code.tex'
open source     > level 3, order 20, name 'pgfcore.code.tex'
open source     > level 4, order 21, name 'pgfmath.code.tex'
open source     > level 5, order 22, name 'pgfmathcalc.code.tex'
open source     > level 6, order 23, name 'pgfmathutil.code.tex'
close source    > level 6, order 23, name 'pgfmathutil.code.tex'
open source     > level 6, order 24, name 'pgfmathparser.code.tex'
close source    > level 6, order 24, name 'pgfmathparser.code.tex'
open source     > level 6, order 25, name 'pgfmathfunctions.code.tex'
open source     > level 7, order 26, name 'pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex'
close source    > level 7, order 26, name 'pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex'
open source     > level 7, order 27, name 'pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex'
close source    > level 7, order 27, name 'pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex'
open source     > level 7, order 28, name 'pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex'
close source    > level 7, order 28, name 'pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex'
open source     > level 7, order 29, name 'pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex'
close source    > level 7, order 29, name 'pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex'
open source     > level 7, order 30, name 'pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex'
close source    > level 7, order 30, name 'pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex'
open source     > level 7, order 31, name 'pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex'
close source    > level 7, order 31, name 'pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex'
open source     > level 7, order 32, name 'pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex'
close source    > level 7, order 32, name 'pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex'
open source     > level 7, order 33, name 'pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex'
close source    > level 7, order 33, name 'pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex'
close source    > level 6, order 33, name 'pgfmathfunctions.code.tex'
close source    > level 5, order 33, name 'pgfmathcalc.code.tex'
open source     > level 5, order 34, name 'pgfmathfloat.code.tex'
close source    > level 5, order 34, name 'pgfmathfloat.code.tex'
close source    > level 4, order 34, name 'pgfmath.code.tex'
open source     > level 4, order 35, name 'pgfcorepoints.code.tex'
close source    > level 4, order 35, name 'pgfcorepoints.code.tex'
open source     > level 4, order 36, name 'pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex'
close source    > level 4, order 36, name 'pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex'
open source     > level 4, order 37, name 'pgfcorepathusage.code.tex'
close source    > level 4, order 37, name 'pgfcorepathusage.code.tex'
open source     > level 4, order 38, name 'pgfcorescopes.code.tex'
close source    > level 4, order 38, name 'pgfcorescopes.code.tex'
open source     > level 4, order 39, name 'pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex'
close source    > level 4, order 39, name 'pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex'
open source     > level 4, order 40, name 'pgfcoretransformations.code.tex'
close source    > level 4, order 40, name 'pgfcoretransformations.code.tex'
open source     > level 4, order 41, name 'pgfcorequick.code.tex'
close source    > level 4, order 41, name 'pgfcorequick.code.tex'
open source     > level 4, order 42, name 'pgfcoreobjects.code.tex'
close source    > level 4, order 42, name 'pgfcoreobjects.code.tex'
open source     > level 4, order 43, name 'pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex'
close source    > level 4, order 43, name 'pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex'
open source     > level 4, order 44, name 'pgfcorearrows.code.tex'
close source    > level 4, order 44, name 'pgfcorearrows.code.tex'
open source     > level 4, order 45, name 'pgfcoreshade.code.tex'
close source    > level 4, order 45, name 'pgfcoreshade.code.tex'
open source     > level 4, order 46, name 'pgfcoreimage.code.tex'
open source     > level 5, order 47, name 'pgfcoreexternal.code.tex'
close source    > level 5, order 47, name 'pgfcoreexternal.code.tex'
close source    > level 4, order 47, name 'pgfcoreimage.code.tex'
open source     > level 4, order 48, name 'pgfcorelayers.code.tex'
close source    > level 4, order 48, name 'pgfcorelayers.code.tex'
open source     > level 4, order 49, name 'pgfcoretransparency.code.tex'
close source    > level 4, order 49, name 'pgfcoretransparency.code.tex'
open source     > level 4, order 50, name 'pgfcorepatterns.code.tex'
close source    > level 4, order 50, name 'pgfcorepatterns.code.tex'
open source     > level 4, order 51, name 'pgfcorerdf.code.tex'
close source    > level 4, order 51, name 'pgfcorerdf.code.tex'
close source    > level 3, order 51, name 'pgfcore.code.tex'
open source     > level 3, order 52, name 'pgffor.code.tex'
open source     > level 4, order 53, name 'pgfmath.code.tex'
close source    > level 4, order 53, name 'pgfmath.code.tex'
close source    > level 3, order 53, name 'pgffor.code.tex'
open source     > level 3, order 54, name 'pgfmoduleplot.code.tex'
close source    > level 3, order 54, name 'pgfmoduleplot.code.tex'
open source     > level 3, order 55, name 'tikz.code.tex'
open source     > level 4, order 56, name 'pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex'
close source    > level 4, order 56, name 'pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex'
open source     > level 4, order 57, name 'pgfmodulematrix.code.tex'
open source     > level 5, order 58, name 'pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex'
close source    > level 5, order 58, name 'pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex'
close source    > level 4, order 58, name 'pgfmodulematrix.code.tex'
open source     > level 4, order 59, name 'tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex'
close source    > level 4, order 59, name 'tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex'
close source    > level 3, order 59, name 'tikz.code.tex'
open source     > level 3, order 60, name 'pgfmoduleplot.code.tex'
close source    > level 3, order 60, name 'pgfmoduleplot.code.tex'
open source     > level 3, order 61, name 'pgfmoduledecorations.code.tex'
close source    > level 3, order 61, name 'pgfmoduledecorations.code.tex'
close source    > level 2, order 61, name '/home/aviroum/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/modules/mkxl/m-tikz.mkxl'
open source     > level 2, order 62, name 'tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex'
close source    > level 2, order 62, name 'tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex'
open source     > level 2, order 63, name 'tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex'
close source    > level 2, order 63, name 'tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex'
modules         > 'fullpage' is loaded
open source     > level 2, order 64, name '/home/aviroum/context/tex/texmf-modules/t-fullpage/tex/context/third/fullpage/t-fullpage.mkiv'
loading         > ConTeXt User Module / Fullpage
close source    > level 2, order 64, name '/home/aviroum/context/tex/texmf-modules/t-fullpage/tex/context/third/fullpage/t-fullpage.mkiv'
tex error       > tex error on line 62 in file ./main.tex: Control sequence expected instead of undefined

<argument> 
    \hoffset 
<macro> \pgfqpoint 
    #1#2->\global \pgf@x =#1
    \relax \global \pgf@y =#2\relax 
<macro> \pgf@process 
    #1->{#1
    \global \pgf@x =\pgf@x \global \pgf@y =\pgf@y }
<macro> \pgf@shape@interpictureshift 
    ...gfpictureid }\pgf@shape@current@pos \pgf@xa =\pgf@x \pgf@ya =\pgf@y \pgf@process {\pgfpointorigin \pgf@shape@current@pos }\advance \pgf@xa by-\pgf@x \advance \pgf@ya by-\pgf@y \pgf@process {\pgfpointorigin \pgf@shape@original@pos }
    \advance \pgf ...
<argument> 
    ...\csname pgf@sh@ns@\tikz@pp@name {current page}\endcsname }{south west}{\pgfsettransform {\csname pgf@sh@nt@\tikz@pp@name {current page}\endcsname }\pgf@pos@transform@glob }\pgf@shape@interpictureshift {\tikz@pp@name {current page}}
    \pgftransform ...
<macro> \pgf@process 
    #1->{#1
    \global \pgf@x =\pgf@x \global \pgf@y =\pgf@y }
 ...

<line 3.62> 
       \draw[bleu,step=2mm](current page.south west)
     grid (current page.north east);

52        
53     
54     %OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
55     %OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
56        \starttext
57     %OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
58     %OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
59     
60        
61        \starttikzpicture[remember picture,overlay]
62 >>     \draw[bleu,step=2mm](current page.south west) grid (current page.north east);  
63        \stoptikzpicture
64        
65        
66        
67        
68        \stoptext
69        %OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
You injected something that confused the parser, maybe by using some Lua call.
```

main-error.log :

```
return {
 ["errortype"]=0,
 ["filename"]="./main.tex",
 ["lastcontext"]="\n<argument> \n    \\hoffset \n<macro> \\pgfqpoint \n    #1#2->\\global \\pgf@x =#1\n    \\relax \\global \\pgf@y =#2\\relax \n<macro> \\pgf@process \n    #1->{#1\n    \\global \\pgf@x =\\pgf@x \\global \\pgf@y =\\pgf@y }\n<macro> \\pgf@shape@interpictureshift \n    ...gfpictureid }\\pgf@shape@current@pos \\pgf@xa =\\pgf@x \\pgf@ya =\\pgf@y \\pgf@process {\\pgfpointorigin \\pgf@shape@current@pos }\\advance \\pgf@xa by-\\pgf@x \\advance \\pgf@ya by-\\pgf@y \\pgf@process {\\pgfpointorigin \\pgf@shape@original@pos }\n    \\advance \\pgf ...\n<argument> \n    ...\\csname pgf@sh@ns@\\tikz@pp@name {current page}\\endcsname }{south west}{\\pgfsettransform {\\csname pgf@sh@nt@\\tikz@pp@name {current page}\\endcsname }\\pgf@pos@transform@glob }\\pgf@shape@interpictureshift {\\tikz@pp@name {current page}}\n    \\pgftransform ...\n<macro> \\pgf@process \n    #1->{#1\n    \\global \\pgf@x =\\pgf@x \\global \\pgf@y =\\pgf@y }\n ...\n\n<line 3.62> \n       \\draw[bleu,step=2mm](current page.south west)\n     grid (current page.north east);\n\n",
 ["lastluaerror"]="",
 ["lasttexerror"]="Control sequence expected instead of undefined",
 ["lasttexhelp"]="You injected something that confused the parser, maybe by using some Lua call.",
 ["linenumber"]=62,
 ["offset"]=10,
 ["skiplinenumber"]=62,
}
```

Is there any guide to explain errors like in latex.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's no `clac` library. Probably you meant `calc`? Or is the typo deliberate?

Comment: Yes, I edit the code :)

Comment: Did you see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/492097/cannot-remember-picture-with-tikz-in-context?rq=1? I didn't follow the link, so I don't know if the problem in ConTeXt is solved or you still need the workaround.

Comment: Yes I did, Is it the same problem? In my humble opinion I don't think so. I am biginner.

Comment: I think you might get better help on this if you send a mail to [the ConTeXT mailing list](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Mailing_Lists). Don't forget to include the minimal example. (ConTeXt is made to fit with MetaPost/MetaFun, so using that might be an option.)

Comment: I don't know. I agree with @mickep about the mailing list. But if that bug isn't fixed, it will be a problem even if there's another, prior problem in your specific case. As I understand it, the problem there means `remember picture` will give a fatal error. You're using `remember picture`. Hence, if the problem isn't fixed, you'll need the workaround. But perhaps it is fixed. Do you have problems without `remember picture,overlay`? If not, I'd definitely look into it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link to the report is broken, so it is not an easy thing to look into. I'd include the reference when mailing the mailing list, though. They should know where to find it, if it is to be found.

Comment: It's the `current page` references which seem to cause the problem. Does `context` use `dvips`? While I don't think it should error, I'm not sure it is supposed to work either. See page 1143 of the pgf manual sec. 106.4 Special Nodes > Predefined node `current page` where the documentation is quite explicit about reliance on the backend. But I'd consider it to be a bug if it doesn't do what it is supposed to, even in that case, which is just to typeset stuff *here* rather than wherever you specify.

Comment: I don't know enough about ConTeXt to even know if it is supposed to be using the `pdftex` driver for PGF. On my machine it's using `luatex` instead, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: See https://mailman.ntg.nl/archives/list/ntg-context@ntg.nl/thread/OG2JJLQSAIN5Q4DCZRCU3KSY7HY5JNHX/#AQXO3XLTN3FEAVF4HARZMKDPBSOERQN6 for discussion. Not clear to me what the current status is.

Comment: Thank you for your comments,. in this case the best way is to send  mail to [the Context mailing list](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Mailing_Lists.)

Comment: The error is because `\hoffset` and `\voffset` are not defined in ConTeXt. But that's not the whole story. After I add `\newdim\hoffset` and `\newdimen\voffset`, there are subsequent error messages. So, something else is also going on.

Comment: Please upgrade your installation and try if it works now.

Answer (score 2):

The first issue is due to the missing definitions for `\hoffset` and `\voffset`. See [Aditya's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/696234/270600) for more on that.

The second issue here is that due to some internal operations, on the Lua side `\lastxpos` is an integer while `\lastypos` is a float. When this is sent to TeX, this is what it sees:

```tex
\numexpr 12345\relax % \lastxpos
\numexpr 123.5\relax % \lastypos
```

`\numexpr` stops expanding after the first non-expandable or non-digit token. For `\lastxpos`, that's the `\relax` (which expands to nothing and disappears); but for `\lastypos`, that's the decimal point (`.`), so the `\relax` at the end is left in the token stream.

[The ConTeXt developers have already acknowledged this](https://mailman.ntg.nl/archives/list/ntg-context@ntg.nl/thread/REQSYIQVFUBB3CXRVOG64MYBXBVPHARK/), so you the best solution would be to wait until the next update.

Alternatively, you can use this temporary workaround:

```tex
% See Aditya's answer
\newdimen\hoffset
\newdimen\voffset

% \last[xy]pos fix:
\startluacode
interfaces.implement {
    name = "lastxpos",
    actions = function() context("%.0f", job.positions.lastx) end
}
interfaces.implement {
    name = "lastypos",
    actions = function() context("%.0f", job.positions.lasty) end
}
\stopluacode

% Original, unmodified code:
\setuppapersize[A4]
\usemodule[tikz]
\usetikzlibrary[calc,positioning]
\usemodule[fullpage][style={cm,empty}]
\setupfullpage [margin=0cm]
\usecolors[crayola]
\definecolor[bleu][x=3bbaba]
\starttext
\starttikzpicture[remember picture,overlay]
 \draw[bleu,step=2mm](current page.south west) grid (current page.north east);
 \stoptikzpicture

\stoptext
```

[image: output]

Comment: Fixed in latest beta

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: This has been fixed in context version `2023.09.17 09:30`

This is a long comment to explain what is going on.

First, `\hoffset` and `\voffset` are not defined in ConTeXt. I don't know what they are supposed to represent in LaTeX, but let's just add their definition. (I also removed all unnecessary code from the example).

```
\newdimen\hoffset
\newdimen\voffset
\usemodule[tikz]

\starttext
\starttikzpicture[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw(current page.south west) grid (current page.north east);  
\stoptikzpicture

\stoptext
```

This runs fine when you compile it the first time. The second run gives the error:

```
tex error       > tex error on line 7 in file ./test.tex: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)

<to be read again>

    \relax
<argument>
    46204089.0\relax
    sp
<macro> \pgfqpoint
    #1#2->\global \pgf@x =#1\relax \global \pgf@y =#2
    \relax
<macro> \pgf@process
    #1->{#1
    \global \pgf@x =\pgf@x \global \pgf@y =\pgf@y }
<macro> \pgf@shape@interpictureshift
    ...id \else \pgfsys@getposition {\csname pgf@sh@pi@#1\endcsname }\pgf@shape@original@pos \pgfsys@getposition {\pgfpictureid }\pgf@shape@current@pos \pgf@xa =\pgf@x \pgf@ya =\pgf@y \pgf@process {\pgfpointorigin \pgf@shape@current@pos}
    \advance \pgf ...
<argument>
    ...\csname pgf@sh@ns@\tikz@pp@name {current page}\endcsname }{south west}{\pgfsettransform {\csname pgf@sh@nt@\tikz@pp@name {current page}\endcsname }\pgf@pos@transform@glob }\pgf@shape@interpictureshift {\tikz@pp@name {current page}}
    \pgftransform ...
 ...

<line 3.7>
          \draw(current page.south west)
     grid (current page.north east);

 1         \newdimen\hoffset
 2         \newdimen\voffset
 3         \usemodule[tikz]
 4
 5         \starttext
 6         \starttikzpicture[remember picture,overlay]
 7 >>        \draw(current page.south west) grid (current page.north east);
 8         \stoptikzpicture
 9
10         \stoptext
11
```

The reason for this error is that TikZ has written a file `\jobname.pgf` which contains:

```
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid1}{4661756}{46204089.0\relax }
```

Notice the extra `\relax` at the end. When this file is read, TikZ tries to call the macro:

```
\def\pgfsyspdfmark#1#2#3{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname pgf@sys@pdf@mark@pos@#1\endcsname{\pgfqpoint{#2sp}{#3sp}}%
  \pgfutil@check@rerun{#1}{{#2}{#3}}%
}
```

which causes the error because `46204089.0\relax sp` is not a valid dimension.

I don't understand why the `\relax` gets written to the pgf file. The code for writing the content is:

```
\def\pgfsys@markposition#1{%
  \savepos%
  \edef\pgf@temp{#1}%
  \expandafter\pgfutil@writetoaux\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\noexpand\expandafter\pgfsyspdfmark\expandafter{\pgf@temp}{\the\lastxpos}{\the\lastypos}}%
}
```

This is not an expansion issue. Somehow `\lastypos` behaves differently than `\lastxpos` (if I change the order of the two commands, even then the `\relax` is with the `ypos`.

Comment: @cfr `ConTeXt` use `LuaMetaTeX` as the the underlying engine, and most (or even all?) primitives related to the backend are not defined there. The idea with this engine is to keep all the algorithms that TeX use layout the page (line/page breaking, glue calculation, box construction etc. ) while removing all "extensions" that are not related to this aspect (file searching, writing/reading files, even the creation of log file, or the desired output) and implement them in Lua. So it is not that surprising that `\hoffset` is not implemented.

Comment: @cfr Even in LuaTeX there is a substitute to `\hoffset`, that is called `\pageleftoffset` that does not contain the annoying `1in` by default. So we can guess someone did not like `\hoffset` but kept it for tradition in LuaTeX. Note that while  `LuaMetaTeX` removes allot it also adds some really handy primitives to ease the programing in TeX. For example [see this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/694827/264024).

Comment: @cfr [LuaMetaTeX Reference Manual §1.3.2](https://texdoc.org/serve/luametatex/0#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A33%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22Fit%22%7D%5D): “The following primitives are available in LuaTeX but not in LuaMetaTeX. Some of these are emulated in ConTeXt […] `hoffset` […] `lastxpos` `lastypos` […] `voffset`”

Comment: @cfr Yes, it was removed as it is not necessary. This register keeps information for the output file only (pdf, dvi or anything else).

Comment: @UdiFogiel I'm going to tidy up.

Comment: It actually looks like a bug in lastypos, I get the spurious `\relax` even with `\starttext
a\savepos
\newwrite\test
\openout\test=test.txt
\write\test{(\the\lastxpos,\the\lastypos)}
\stoptext`

Comment: @UdiFogiel yes, I had posted a bug report to the context mailing list yst. Let's see how it gets resolved.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answers. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. The pdf is generated, but the grid position is wrong. I think I'll have to wait until the next update.

Answer (score 1):

Although this has been fixed in the latest release, I am posting another answer to show how to achieve the same result without using `remember picture`. Of course, the ConTeXtish solution would be to use MetaPost but we don't have to.

ConTeXt has this nice feature call [overlays](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Overlays) and basically you can place whatever you want in an overlay (including a tikzpicture!).

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\usecolors[crayola]
\definecolor[bleu][x=3bbaba]

\startsetups tikz:grid
\starttikzpicture
   \draw[bleu,step=2mm] (0,0) grid (\overlaywidth,\overlayheight);
\stoptikzpicture
\stopsetups

\defineoverlay
  [background:grid]
  [\setups{tikz:grid}]

\setupbackgrounds[page][background=background:grid]

\starttext
\input ward
\stoptext
```

The nice feature of this solution is that this not only works with page backgrounds, but for anything for which there is a `background` key. For example:

```
\startframedtext[background=background:grid]
\input ward
\stopframedtext
```

Comment: Thank you @Aditya. Your answer is perfect for using background. My question is how to get ride with using `remember picture, overlay` in `context` . I wrote a bad example.